# can't render element of type <class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.UUID'>

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I saw this snippet of code from [Flask-common](https://github.com/closeio/flask-common/blob/master/flask_common/db.py#L57) at line 57:

```
id = db.Column(UUID, default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), primary_key=True)
```

So I thought I give it a try and use it in my app's `models.py` (because I prefer to have `uuid` type for my id's)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
import uuid

from app import db

class CostCenter(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "costcenter"

    id = db.Column('id', UUID(as_uuid=True), default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column('name', db.Text)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)
```

But when I try to run `python manage.py db upgrade`, it results to an error:

```
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 190, in __init__                                                          
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 213, in process                                                           
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 81, in _compiler_dispatch                                                 
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2164, in visit_create_table                                               
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause                                                   
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2153, in visit_create_table                                               
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 213, in process                                                           
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 81, in _compiler_dispatch                                                 
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2184, in visit_create_column                                              
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py", line 847, in get_column_specification                                  
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 261, in process                                                           
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 79, in _compiler_dispatch                                                 
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: (in table 'costcenter', column 'id'): Compiler <sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.base.SQLiteTypeCompiler object at 0x7fc16
c1f1a50> can't render element of type <class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.UUID'>
```

Why can't it render the type UUID? It is recognized in `SQLAlchemy` but how come it can't in `Flask-SQLAlchemy`?

Comment: You can't use a Postgres data type with SQLite. They're two different databases.

Comment: For anyone who gets here and is thinking "but I didn't set my database to sqlite!" -- you probably aren't passing in your postgres connection information into sqlalchemy properly, and so it is _defaulting_ to using sqlite as the database. Check your DB configuration information.

Comment: Is there an alternative, where depending on the database type you are working with, it runs one line or another?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your column definition is using a function that only works with postgresql, and your database type is sqlite.

You need this:

```
id = db.Column(
  'id', 
  db.Text(length=36), 
  default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), 
  primary_key=True)
```

Comment: I only read this by now but it so happened I also resorted to a `Text` column too. Thanks for this though.

Comment: Text also isn't available in sqlite? I thought all SQLALchemy().types where utilizable in any kind of db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UUID` just in case of using **postgresql** database.